# Going between the abstract and the concrete notions of chiral homology

Tags: configuration-spaces, vertex-algebras, chiral-homology

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic curve over $\mathbf{C}$, and let $\mathcal{V}$ be a factorisation algebra over $X$, whose fibre above $x\in X$ is the vertex algebra $V$.

Note that $\mathcal{V}\in\mathcal{D}\text{-mod}(\text{Ran}X)$. In particular, taking the projection $p:\text{Ran}X\to \text{pt}$ we can define its **chiral cohomology** as its de Rham cohomology $\text{H}^*_{ch}(X,\mathcal{V}):=p_*\mathcal{V}$. Similarly **chiral homology** is $p_!\mathcal{V}$.

There is also (c.f. Frenkel-Ben Zvi's book) the notion of **coinvariants**. You take the complex
$$\mathcal{V}\otimes \Omega^*_X\ =\ \mathcal{V}\to\mathcal{V}\otimes\Omega^1_X$$
and set $U_Y=\Gamma(Y,H^1(\mathcal{V}\otimes\Omega^1_X))$ for $Y\subseteq X$. This acts on $V$ via the map $U_Y\to U_{D_x^\times}\to \text{End}V$ where $D_x^\times$ is the formal disk around $X$. The space of coinvariants then is
$$H(X,x,V)\ =\ V/(U_{X\setminus x}(V)\cdot V).$$

**Question:** Why is $H^0_{ch}(X,\mathcal{V})=H(X,x,V)$? This is referenced in 20.2.6 of Frenkel-Ben Zvi's book.

I am interested in this question because I have no idea how you would even begin to compute de Rham cohomology for D modules over the Ran space, and this seemed like the simplest example of that.

Comment: This is because the spectral sequence associated to the Cousin filtration stabilizes in the first page, so the zeroth homology of the Cousin complex on X^n gives the right answer for any n. The case n=1 is the case treated in FBZ. If no one gives a complete answer in a couple of weeks ping me and I'll type it